# Outlier detection of time series with One Class Support Vector Machine

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, outliers, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to detect outliers in a time series data using the one class support vector machine from Sklearn. My problem is that every point is classified as an outlier, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
#data consists of [index of value, value]
outliers_fraction = 0.01
model = OneClassSVM(nu=outliers_fraction, kernel="rbf", gamma='auto')
model.fit(data)
df['anomaly'] = pd.Series(model.predict(data))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
a = df.loc[df['anomaly'] == -1, ['DateTime(UTC+01:00)','feature'] ]#anomaly
ax.plot(df['DateTime(UTC+01:00)'], df['feature'], color='blue')
ax.scatter(a['DateTime(UTC+01:00)'],a['feature'], color='red')
```

And here is my result: [Outliers in time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLpjE.png)
The red dots represents the outliers. As you can see every point is classified as an outlier. I would expect every point after a jump to be classified as an outlier.

Edit: added the score_samples

[score_samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u19cb.png)

Comment: You should plot/check the anomaly score, using score_samples

Comment: How does your features look like? If it is just the raw values of each data point, then there is no way for it to express the kind of step change that you consider to be anomalous

Comment: Yes, my features is only the index and the value of the measurement from my data. What features is good for catching the steps? the derivatives?

@JonNordby

Comment: Yes the first order difference is very effective for these kinds of anomalies. You may want to resample the time-series to handle jumps that occur over more than one timestep.